Is it possible to create an on-premise SQL connections via a PowerAutomate flow, HTTP call, or powershell command?
I'm trying to create an SQL server connection in several different environments in my Power Platform organization. I came across the Power Automate Management "Create Connection" action in a cloud flow, but found that it didn't have a parameter/any capability to enable my on-premise data gateway for the connection and wouldn't let me configure it after the connection was created.
By peeking at the code in the "Create Connection" action I found the url https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_flowmanagement with an operation id "CreateConnection"; when I tried sending the payload below in the body of an HTTP request, I kept getting errors along the lines of "action on scope apis is disallowed". When I tried using this method in powershell I got a similar response; I tried retrieving a token at https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token and using the Bearer token as the authentication method instead but got the same error. Is it possible to achieve this with an HTTP call, or is there another way to automate SQL server connections in Power Automate with on-premise data gateways configured?
{
    "host":{
        "connectionName": "shared_flowmanagement",
        "operationId": "CreateConnection",
        "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_flowmanagement"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "environmentName": "{env name}",
        "apiName": "shared_sql",
        "connection/properties/connectionParameters/server": "{servername}",
        "connection/properties/connectionParameters/database": "{db name}",
        "connection/properties/connectionParameters/authType": "SQL Server Authentication",
        "connection/properties/connectionParameters/username": "{SQL username}",
        "connection/properties/connectionParameters/password": "{password}"
    }
}


Didn't you ask this question already?

The connection properties are in the HTTP JSON body.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/http-connectors/4-http-request  So in powershell you can use Invoke-WebRequest with a json body : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4

I figured it out!
I was unable to do this via an HTTP call; instead, I used the Power Automate "Create Connection" action but input a custom connection rather than just using the pre-loaded SQL Server option. I dynamically set the connector id to 'shared_sql' by using the following string s = providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/.../shared_sql and setting the value to last(split(s, '/')). Then, I set the connectionParameters to the following:
{
 "authType": "Basic",
 "gateway":{
     "gatewayId":"{gatewayid}"
   }
 "server": "{server name}",
 "database": "{dbname}",
 "username": "{username}",
 "password": "{password}"
}

Note: For some reason, this payload only works in the old Power Automate designer. Hope this helps anyone running into this issue!
